# 'flutterfire configure' command not working, I need to set firebase in my flutter project

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I followed "https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview" instruction to set firebase in my flutter project.

step i took:

1. "flutter pub add firebase_core" then dependencies were added, and generated_plugin_registrant.dart was created.
   [generated_plugin_registrant.dart file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXbZD.png)

2) "dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli" it showed an warnign message ie "Warning: Pub installs executables into C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\bin, which is not on your path.
You can fix that by adding that directory to your system's "Path" environment variable.
A web search for "configure windows path" will show you how.
Activated flutterfire_cli 0.1.1+2."

3. then i added "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\bin" in system; "path" environment variable.
4. "flutterfire configure" now it gives error "bash: flutterfire: command not found".

Comment: have you tried closing and reopening the console after adding the bin to the path?

Comment: @h8moss yes! it did not work

Answer (score 42):

Step by step commands for getting flutterfire work in Mac:

```
dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli  
export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/.pub-cache/bin"
curl -sL https://firebase.tools | bash  
firebase login
flutterfire configure
```

[More details here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview#initializing-flutterfire)

Comment: Yeah for mac this definitely worked for me. Thank you so much!

Comment: its 2023 and i found this is the best solution. works like a charm!

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem. Following command worked for me (in Windows).

```
flutterfire.bat configure
```

Answer (score 13):

**Windows Step-by-Step guide**:

1. Open the Windows Search Bar, type in “env”, and choose “Edit the system environment variables”
2. Click the “Environment Variables…”
3. In System Variables box, search for "PATH" and double click on it
4. Click "New" and then paste the following line, replacing `*USERNAME*` with your Windows username

   `C:\Users\*USERNAME*\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\bin`
5. Click Ok and restart your IDE, then try `flutterfire` commands

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem and I solved this by:

1. Added `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\bin` to Environment Path.
2. Restarted IDE
3. Executed command: `dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli`

Answer (score 1):

For me it wasn't working in bash.  When i switched over to the standard windows comand prompt it worked.

Answer (score 1):

If using **GitBash** you have to add `.bat`:
`flutterfire.bat configure`
(thank you ST24)

If using **PowerShell** you can run:
`flutterfire configure`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that worked for me:

1. From your terminal,open your bash profile in your home directory. Example home directory, Users/your-name/. I'm using macOS, so I typed typed the command sudo vim ~/.bash_profile from my home directory folder, followed by E to edit.
2. Scroll to the bottom of the file or below # Flutter ENV, on your keyboard, hit i to insert, then paste the following line, export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/.pub-cache/bin". Press ESC, type ":wq!" then press Enter to save the changes and exit vim.
3. From the command line, reload your bash profile with source ~/.bash_profile. flutterfire configure should now work.

Answer (score 0):

Hrishabh
This worked for me.

Close your IDE.
Restart IDE.
Re-run "flutter pub add firebase_core" in your terminal.
Finally run "dart pub global acttivate flutterfire_cli" in your terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem here is the way to solve it:

```
Warning: Pub installs executables into C:\Users\userName\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\bin, which is not on your path.
You can fix that by adding that directory to your system's "Path" environment variable.
```

1. Go the Windows searchbar and write var
2. Select modify system environment
3. Click on environment variables
4. On system variables click on Path
5. Click on Edit
6. On the modify the environment variable windows click on New
7. Copy paste C:\Users\userName\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\bin
8. Close all the windows clicking on Ok
9. Restart Android Studio
10. Inside Android Studio terminal write this to check if succeed

    **dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli**

You should have the following message:

```
The package flutterfire_cli is already activated at newest available version.
```

Answer (score 0):

On windows, from flutter root folder, running 'flutterfire configure' I got the same error message.

The 'problem' was resolved when I removed the following lines from pubspec.yaml.

```
  plugin:
    platforms:
      ios:
        pluginClass: AppDelegate
```

(I added those lines in an attempt to create a "podfile" that is required in order to create a binary ios file. )

Answer (score 0):

For me it required a little bit more work but this is what worked for me, I'm using Windows:

As mentioned already before I ran these steps:

1). Search for "Edit System Environment Variables"
2). Click on Environment Variables
3). Under System Variables, double click on "path."
4). Click on "New" and add C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\bin
5). Click OK and restart IDE

After restarting IDE I ran the following commands in the terminal and this time it worked

1). Firstly, **flutter upgrade firebase_core**
2). Then, I ran **dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli** again and this time when I ran flutterfire commands it worked.

Answer (score 0):

"After setting the PATH environment variable, you need to restart your terminal for the changes to take effect. If you're using the terminal in Visual Studio Code, you'll need to restart Visual Studio Code. This should resolve the issue and allow the command to work."